# PayPal Advanced Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I have been trying to validate that when the silent post comes into my application it is validated that it is indeed from Paypal. I have tried both in the following link.

[PayPal Payments Advanced -- Validate Parameters Sent to Confirm and Cancel Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122293/paypal-payments-advanced-validate-parameters-sent-to-confirm-and-cancel-pages)

Neither seems to work. When i try to pass a token it just does not send. If I do it manually it works but it seems the regular params sent with Paypal "override it".

I tried using NVP/SOAP and Rest API and neither of them work either.

I JUST need a simple way that will WORK to know that the silent post I am receiving is Paypal and a valid transaction 100%. A secure token would seem to work great but no cigar so far.

Application is in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I have implemented a PayPal Api using the recommedations found at RailsCast. But I am not sure how up to date these videos are. One big problem at this time was that they where using windows encoding... http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=paypal

Comment: did you check out paypal webhooks? Haven't done it, just a guess. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest/webhooks/

Comment: @maxpleaner - This is for rest which is entirely seperate. I already tried validating payments through rest and it just doesn't work.

Comment: @Mark I need to confirm validation for paypal advanced specifically with its inline checkin callback

Answer (score 0):

If this is still not working for you, you might want to check on the URL from which you receive the silent post

URL: notify.paypal.com (Payflow Silent Post)
IP address: 173.0.81.65

Here is a pro module documentation from broadleafcommerce.com

http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/paypal-payflowpro/current/paypal-payflow-pro-environment-setup

Found something similar here

[How do you verify that the notification to the Silent Post URL is indeed from PayPal Payflow and not a hacker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148603/how-do-you-verify-that-the-notification-to-the-silent-post-url-is-indeed-from-pa)